# Android Image recognition

Tags: android, image-recognition

I have a particular problem about image recognition on Android.
I am looking for some library able to recognize several objects from a photo. For instance, given a photo snapped by the user how can I count how many red circles and yellow triangles there are? Those shapes are just an example, since I want to recognize images which are pretty simple.
I have seen that there exists a good framework called Vuforia, which is designed for augmented reality. Do you think it is right for me? I am not an expert, so I ask you to help me.

Answer (score 4):

check [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html) for that, open source and works great on android

or

[OpenCv](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html)